# For every set of Y rows, copy the first n rows from a dataframe with X rows (where X is some multiple of Y)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Let's say there is some dataframe with X rows (e.g., 25). How would I go about copying the first 3 rows (e.g., index 0, 1, 2) and excluding the next 2 (e.g., index 3, 4), then repeating this every 5 rows (include index 5, 6, 7; exclude 8, 9; ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a list of the row indices you want, then pass them to `df.iloc`:

```
include = 3
for_each = 5

indices = [index for i in range(0, len(df), for_each) for index in range(i, i+include)]
df.iloc[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use remainder division to subset rows of the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(15))

N = 5     # Sets of this many rows
keep = 3  # Keep this many in each N

m = (df.reset_index().index%N) < keep
       # reset incase not RangeIndex

df[m]
#     0
#0    0
#1    1
#2    2
#5    5
#6    6
#7    7
#10  10
#11  11
#12  12
```